# English version of "Quasi-Hopf Algebras"

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, absolute-galois-group

I was wondering where I can find a pdf of Drinfeld's paper "Quasi-Hopf Algebras," which formulated the Grothendieck-Teichmuller group.  The Russian version is in Algebra i Analiz, 1:6 (1989), 114–148, and the English version is in Leningrad Mathematical Journal, 1990, 1:6, 1419–1457.

Comment: Speak to your local librarian (yes, a human being), who can request a scan of a copy if your local library doesn't have it. Or if you know faculty or students at a university that holds the journal, you could ask them to make a scan for you.

Comment: Send me an e-mail and I'll send you a copy.

Comment: Legalities pf sharing aside, the English translation occurs in a journal distributed by AMS which probably has fairly accurate translations.   (Sometimes untrue for commercial translation journals.)